# How to re-scale my data while keeping the same distribution

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, statistics, distribution

```py
   month  value
0      1    866
1      2    274
2      3    975
3      4    792
4      5    512
5      6    610
6      7    980
7      8    984
8      9    602
9     10    177
```

Say I have this data, I am wondering whether it is possible to distribute the data in like 6 months while keeping the same distribution.

Hope I'm not unclear and excuse me if I got the terminology wrong.
Thank you.

Comment: So you want to pretend these 10 months of data occurred over 6 months?  Do you want the total to remain the same?

Comment: Yes exactly that

Comment: Seems to me you'd have to make some assumptions on how to interpolate, given that 10 is not an integer multiple of 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to know if your value is concentrated at one end of the month or the other.  The simplest thing then is to assume it's evenly distributed over the month.  So each output month will consist of 10/6 of the input months.  For example output month 1 will consist of 6/6 of input month 1 and 4/6 of input month 2; output month 2 will be the remainder of input month 2 (2/6), 6/6 of input month 3, and 2/6 of input month 4.  The code is actually simpler than the explanation:

```
values = [866, 274, 975, 792, 512, 610, 980, 984, 602, 177]
output = []
fill_count = 0
new_value = 0
in_len = len(values)
out_len = 6
for value in values:
    portion = out_len
    while portion > 0:
        using = min(portion, in_len - fill_count)
        new_value += using * value / out_len
        portion -= using
        fill_count += using
        if fill_count >= in_len:
            output.append(new_value)
            new_value = 0
            fill_count = 0
print(output)
[1048.6666666666667, 1330.3333333333333, 1040.0, 1263.3333333333335, 1511.3333333333335, 578.3333333333333]
print(math.isclose(sum(values), sum(output)))
True
```

Comment: @Tempo I think it would need some minor adjustment to go larger reliably.  Not sure though, you could try it and see what happens.

Comment: Nevermind, it works great both ways, keeping the same total. Thank you so much!